# angular Rxjs subject.next() doesn't work in mobile browser

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

As the below code, which is work in the desktop browser. However, it is doesn't work in the mobile browser. I find it is because of the subject.next() did not send successfully.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmpadm (my codes)

**ToastService.ts**

```
 public subject = new Subject<ToastModel>();

 constructor() {}

 getToast = (toastId?: string): Observable<any> => {
   return this.subject.asObservable();
 };

 success(message: string, keepAfterRouteChange = false) {
  this.toast(ToastType.Success, message, keepAfterRouteChange);
 }

 toast(type: ToastType, message: string, keepAfterRouteChange = false) 
 {
   this.keepAfterRouterChange = keepAfterRouteChange;
   // I think is this code doesn't work
   this.subject.next(<ToastModel>{ type: type, message: message });
 }
```

**toast.component.ts**

```
constructor(private toastService: ToastService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.toastService.getToast().subscribe((toast: ToastModel) => {
    // because in here can not catch the data from subject.next()
    console.log('toast')
    if(!toast) {
      this.toasts = [];
      return;
    }
    this.toasts.push(toast);
  })

  this.toastService.subject.subscribe((toast: ToastModel) => {
    console.log(toast);
  })
}
```

**Above those codes is work in the desktop browser, However, it is not work in the mobile browser**

It is strange, anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi, did you try using BehaviorSubject ?

Comment: How you are checking in the mobile browser? After making a build or in development mode?

Comment: Which browser you are using on mobile phone??

Comment: @Santhoshmp I have tried. However, it is doesn't work.

Comment: @PareshGami @ Abhishek Gautam   Just use the chrome dev tools change to iphone6 mode. No build the project.

Comment: @AbhishekGautam Using the desktop Chrome browser. Switch the device mode by chrome dev tools

Comment: @Stellina can you reproduce the same in the stackblitz?

Comment: @AbhishekGautam I think I find the problem . After buid the preject thoes codes work for me ! It is wired .

Comment: @PareshGami Thinks! After build the project thoes codes it is work for me ! Is is seems you have meet the same problem , if possible ,can you expalin for me why?

Comment: @Stellina. See all the browser does not support ES6 concept now. So when we make build our ES6 code is compiled which is understands by an older browser.

Comment: omg! I made a mistaken test, exactly the problem still exists. I will reproduce the same in the stackblitz.

Comment: @AbhishekGautam https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmpadm

Comment: @Stellina have you correctly imported  BrowserAnimationsModule,
module in your application, add it and check, there is nothing wrong in your code.